# remove noise from image text nodejs

Tags: node.js

how can i remove background noise and leave only the text?
Example image:

[image]

My code:

```
var Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');
var Jimp = require("jimp");


Jimp.read("12.png").then(function (image) {
    image
        .color([
          { apply: 'brighten', params: [20] }
        ])
        .contrast(1)
        .greyscale()
        .write("img-opt.jpg");
})
.then(function() {
  Tesseract.recognize('img-opt.jpg', {
      tessedit_char_whitelist: 'AN%D%P'
  })
    .progress(function(message){console.log(message)})
    .catch(function(err){console.error(err)})
    .then(function(result){console.log(result.text)})
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

And i got this result:

[image]

So, how can i can remove background noise?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got better results by removing the `brigthen` transformation.
Also `desaturate` seems to work better than `grayscale`.

```
image
    .color([{apply: 'desaturate', params: [90]}])
    .contrast(1)
    .write("img-opt.jpg");
```

[image: result]

You just need a little bit of trial and error.

Comment: Omg! Thanks, that works good for me! Is there an option for the tesseract to set the number of characters in image (6), and the fact that all characters are the same size?

Comment: I am not familiar with tesseract, you could try asking another question